# C++ std::set custom comparator

Tags: c++, comparator, stdset

Well, my problem is that I'm using an std::set with a custom comparator, something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int x, int y):
        _x(x), _y(y)
    {
    }

    int hashCode(){ return (_y << 16) | _x; }

private:
    short int _y;
    short int _x;
};

struct comp
{
    bool operator() (A* g1, A* g2) const
    {
        return g1->hashCode() < g2->hashCode();
    }
};
```

So, I use it like

```
std::set<A*, comp> myset;

// Insert some data
A* a = new A(2,1);
A* b = new A(1,3);
myset.insert(a);
myset.insert(b);
```

Now my problem is that I would like to do this:

```
myset.find( (2 << 16) | 1 );
```

But, of course, it excepts A* not short int.

So, I know I could use std::find_if, but won't it render useless the custom comparator? It would iterate the whole list, wouldn't it? Is there any way I could use find with the hashCode rather than the object itself?

Thank you!

Comment: How about std::find_if with the comparator (adjusted for equality)?

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant when I wrote `std::find`, it should have been `std::find_if`. Wouldn't it iterate the whole list, and not optimize the search at all? My reason on using `std::set` is its O(log(n)) search cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set::find` takes argument of type `key_type` (see discussion [Why is set::find not a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066859/why-is-setfind-not-a-template)). Using a std::set you have to construct a temporary object to use `find`.

```
myset.find(A(2, 1));
```

If A is not cheap to construct you might want to use a `std::map<int, A>` (or a wrapper around it) instead.

Comment: A is indeed not cheap. If I were to use a map, would it be better to use a `map` or an `unordered_map`. I'm currently using `google::dense_hash_map` for some other maps with int keys.
Insert cost is not important at all, search cost is.

Comment: @ProStage If ordering doesn't matter you should use `unordered_map` or `unordered_set`.

Comment: @JamesKanze That A is just an example not to write the +100 lines class code. "The thing is the class is not as simple. It actually holds one map which can grow up to 1000 elements. The number of A objects can also grow up to 1000+, all of them unique." (C&P from another comment).
It's constructor is not, by any means, cheap.

Comment: @hansmaad It does not matter in the sense I don't mind the order in which are stored, as long as that doesn't increase it's search time.
I guess an hash table is ideal

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `std::set`, because `std::set<>::find` is
not a (member) template; the argument must be of the key type.
For simple classes like yours, it's likely that using an
`std::vector<A>` and keeping it sorted (using `std::lower_bound`
for lookup, and as the insertion point) will be just as fast.
And with `std::lower_bound`, you can pass in a comparitor, *and*
use any type you want as key.  All you have to do is ensure that
your `comp` class can handle the mixed type comparisons, e.g.:

```
struct Comp
{
    bool operator()( A const&, B const& ) const;
    bool operator()( A const&, int ) const;
    bool operator()( int, A const& ) const;
};
```

Comment: The thing is the class is not as simple. It actually holds one map which can grow up to 1000 elements.
The number of `A` objects can also grow up to 1000+, all of them unique.
Search time/cost is important, and vector wouldn't be an option. Also, threading issues would come when inserting/erasing, as all iterators get invalidated.

Comment: @ProStage Then you'll have to find a work-around.  A vector of `std::shared_ptr` might do the trick; alternatively, you might try to implement a "dummy" version of `A`, which isn't expensive to build, and which could be used as a key into a `std::set`.  (A `map` with no entries isn't expensive to build.  Or just move the implementation, or at least its expensive parts, into a delegate; an instance with a null pointer to the delegate can then be created as an index, and if the delegate is managed with a smart pointer, copy could end up very cheap.)

Answer (score 0):

```
myset.find(&A(2, 1));
```

Or

```
A a(2, 1);
myset.find(&a);
```

Comment: The first is not legal C++.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the compiler.  The standard clearly forbids it (unless class `A` has overridden `operator&`); is a compiler accepts it (when invoked as a C++ compiler), it is broken.  (I'd actually be rather surprised if a compiler accepted it.  This rule, after all, dates from the earliest days of C.  But I've been surprised before at the things some compilers accept.)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `std::set<A*, comp> myset;`, so `std::find()` must take a `A*` argument.

```
std::set<A*, comp> myset;

// Insert some data
A* a = new A(2,1);
A* b = new A(1,3);
myset.insert(a);
myset.insert(b);
```

Then, you need to do

```
myset.find(&A(2,1))
```

Back to your question, `std::find()` is not taking your custom comparator. You need, in fact, to use `std::find_if`.